# Previewing image and video with the spacebar does not work anymore?

Tags: video, preview

[image]

When I press the spacebar on images or videos, my mac used to show me the actual size of the pictures or and videos. For videos, I could play the video without opening the `Preview` app. Somehow it does not work anymore. No clue what setting I'd touched. Is there any way that I can get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've seleccted one file, not more. If it still not working, maybe it's the issue with the keyboard itself.

Comment: I did one file only. And it just opens like that...? Wondering what I can do with the keyboard? I am using M1 Macbook Pro. I used to work on this mac too. And, suddenly this happens (prob some update I guess?).

Comment: Does this happen also in the older versions?

Comment: I really do not remember exactly when this started to be like this. But, I remember I was reviewing pictures with the spacebar with this computer :/ I thought there were some sort of settings that I had to change it.

Comment: It should still work if you select multiple files; it will display the first file in the list, with left/right arrows.

Comment: https://piunikaweb.com/2021/11/05/macos-12-monterey-quick-look-preview-not-working-try-this-workaround/ this was the solution! but thank you so much